# Data in string format sorting as per duration using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have certain data in the form of number of lines containing string. Each line contains date. I want to sort the data for certain duration. e.g. from 12th DEC 2012 to 23rd March 2013. This is supposed to done using javascript and jquery. 
I have done following code.

```
for (TempDate = strFrom; TempDate <= strTo; TempDate.setDate(TempDate.getDate() + 1)) {
    var FromDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', strFrom);
    alert("FromDate : " + FromDate);    
    if (temp1[i].indexOf(FromDate) > 0) {
        $('#BasicDetailsPlaceHolderPanel div:eq(' + i + ')').css({ 'display': 'block'});
    }
    else {
        $('#BasicDetailsPlaceHolderPanel div:eq(' + i + ')').css({ 'display': 'none'});
    }
}
```

But it is showing the records of last date only.
Please tell me solution.

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: What does temp1[i] contain? And in newer browsers you can do temp.indexOf. Also you likely want !=-1 or >=0 because if the temp1[i]==FromDate then the indexOf is ==0

Comment: Where is `temp1` declared and whats in it?

Comment: And where does `i` come from, there's no such variable in the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 // assuming an outer loop on temp1
 for (TempDate = strFrom; TempDate <= strTo; TempDate.setDate(TempDate.getDate() + 1)) {
     var FromDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', strFrom);
     $('#BasicDetailsPlaceHolderPanel div:eq(' + i + ')').css({
       'display':  (temp1[i].indexOf(FromDate) >= 0)?"block":"none"
     });
 }
```